# how to change "<br /></p>" to "</p>" by PHP code?

Tags: php

How to remove all br tags before end of paragraph? 
Actually I want to change

```
<br /></p>
```

to

```
 </p>
```

I use this code

```
$content = preg_replace("/<br \/>(?!.*<br \/>)/","",$content);
```

but it removes all br tags!

Comment: why not just add the <p> tag into the regex equation? o.O

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: @JayBlanchard While I generally agree with needing a DOM parser, I think that the xPath for finding `<br>`s to remove could get tricky due to content-less text() nodes which can exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following regex:

```
/<br\s*\/{0,1}\s*>\s*<\/p>/i
```

will match:

```
<br /></p>
<br / > </p>
<br 
 /></p>
<br> 

</p>
<br ></p>
<br></p>
<br >
</p>
```

case-insensitively.

If you need a step-by-step explanation of the regex then plug it into the "Expression" field at https://regexr.com/

Comment: Some time we have :
<br /></p>
and some time :
<br />
<p>

so str_replace does not work, I think I have to use preg_replace

Comment: actually </p> is in next line !

Comment: there is a one space before </p> so it doesn't work yet ;(

Comment: @SinaPirhadi If my regex helped then please feel free to accept my answer, thanks.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus why not using `\s*` instead of `( |\r\n|\r|\n)*` ?

Comment: `if (!this.Brain.HasBoot()) { this.Brain.Fill(new Coffee()); }`

Comment: @Cid I used `\s*` inside the `<br>` as well since newlines and such are legal in there.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you just want to replace the string <`br /></p>` to `</p>`

Just use str_replace

```
$content = str_replace(array('<br /></p>','<br/></p>'), '</p>', $content);
```

Comment: assign the result to the content: `$content = str_replace('<br /></p>', '</p>', $content);`